# Obtaining position (int) of a QMap::iterator

Tags: c++, qt, qmap

I have written a QListModel based model to access data stored in a QMap. QMap is guaranteed to be sorted. So a conversion from QMap::iterator or const_iterator to int should be possible and sane.

At the moment I decrement the iterator and increment a counter variable:

```
    QVariantMap::iterator it = m_data.upperBound(name); //or any other iterator
    int pos =  0;
    for (;it != m_data.begin();it--)
        pos++;
    //now pos contains the position of the entry at index in the map
```

For some data structures there is an `int operator-(iterator)` defined it seems, allowing `int pos = it - m_data.begin();` is there something similar for QMap?

Comment: probably not, QMap is likely to be implemented with a binary tree so there is no O(1) operation to get the number of elements between 2 nodes

Comment: I'm actually more concerned about line count than performance (n <= 100), it's a red-black tree btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with QMap in particular, but typically, that's the simplest algorithm to find the rank of an element in a map.

Assuming Qt iterators are usable with standard algorithms, you can simplify that to `std::distance(m_data.begin(), it)`. Otherwise, you can implement `distance` for QMap iterators yourself with the algorithm that you showed.